# Modal popup window only works for sharepoint admin

Tags: sharepoint, popup, modal-dialog

I need to add a popup modal to one of the webpart page in our sharepoint 2013 environment as an important notice, it works well when I sign in with the Admin account only, But not with other accounts, can anyone help me out?

Here is the javascript that I have:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('showPopup');

function showPopup() {
  var options = {
    url: myurl + '?IsDlg=1',
    tite: ' Important Notice',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  };
```

Comment: How does it 'not work?' Is the url defined by `myUrl` available to users other than the admin?

Comment: You have some code not published yet. Checkin and publish them all.

Comment: myUrl is available to both users and admins

Comment: the page is checked in and published

Comment: Thanks both for trying to help out, I resolved it with the following :<script language="javascript" type='text/javascript'>

 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('showPopup');

function showPopup() {
  
 
  
     var options = {
         url: 'org Chart.PNG' + '?IsDlg=1',
         tite: 'Organization Chart',
       allowMaximize: false,
         showClose: true,
        width: 800,
         height: 600
         };

     
     
     SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
   
 
 };
 </script>